Undefined Reference For RayLibs when linking with CMake?
I'm trying to use CMake to setup a simple project linking raylibs.  Whenever I try to run my main I keep on getting undeclared references to my function calls:
/usr/bin/ld: /home/doppler/C++ Projects/test 2/source/main.cpp:15: undefined reference to `SetTargetFPS'

Quick Overview of how I began this project:
Created directory, test2, external, source.
Used CMake quick start in VS Code
git cloned raylibs into external
Edited my CMake file;
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.30.0)
project(test2 VERSION 0.1.0 LANGUAGES C CXX)

set(MAIN_PATH source/main.cpp)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${MAIN_PATH})

add_subdirectory(external/raylib)
include_directories("external" "external/raylib/src")
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE raylib)

Opened the terminal in my main directory;
mkdir build
cd build 
cmake --build .

Run main to find no subsequent errors except the blasted undefined references.
Running cmake --build . --verbose returns:
doppler@doppler-Dell-G15-5510:~/C++ Projects/test 2/build$ cmake --build . --verbose
Change Dir: '/home/doppler/C++ Projects/test 2/build'

Run Build Command(s): /home/doppler/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cmake/data/bin/cmake -E env VERBOSE=1 /usr/bin/gmake -f Makefile
/home/doppler/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cmake/data/bin/cmake -S"/home/doppler/C++ Projects/test 2" -B"/home/doppler/C++ Projects/test 2/build" --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
/home/doppler/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cmake/data/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start "/home/doppler/C++ Projects/test 2/build/CMakeFiles" "/home/doppler/C++ Projects/test 2/build//CMakeFiles/progress.marks"
/usr/bin/gmake  -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all
gmake[1]: Entering directory '/home/doppler/C++ Projects/test 2/build'
/usr/bin/gmake  -f external/raylib/raylib/external/glfw/src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/build.make external/raylib/raylib/external/glfw/src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/depend
gmake[2]: Entering directory '/home/doppler/C++ Projects/test 2/build'
cd "/home/doppler/C++ Projects/test 2/build" && /home/doppler/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cmake/data/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" "/home/doppler/C++ Projects/test 2" "/home/doppler/C++ Projects/test 2/external/raylib/src/external/glfw/src" "/home/doppler/C++ Projects/test 2/build" "/home/doppler/C++ Projects/test 2/build/external/raylib/raylib/external/glfw/src" "/home/doppler/C++ Projects/test 2/build/external/raylib/raylib/external/glfw/src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/DependInfo.cmake" "--color="
gmake[2]: Leaving directory '/home/doppler/C++ Projects/test 2/build'
/usr/bin/gmake  -f external/raylib/raylib/external/glfw/src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/build.make external/raylib/raylib/external/glfw/src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/build
gmake[2]: Entering directory '/home/doppler/C++ Projects/test 2/build'
gmake[2]: Nothing to be done for 'external/raylib/raylib/external/glfw/src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/build'.
gmake[2]: Leaving directory '/home/doppler/C++ Projects/test 2/build'
[ 81%] Built target glfw
/usr/bin/gmake  -f external/raylib/raylib/CMakeFiles/raylib.dir/build.make external/raylib/raylib/CMakeFiles/raylib.dir/depend
gmake[2]: Entering directory '/home/doppler/C++ Projects/test 2/build'
cd "/home/doppler/C++ Projects/test 2/build" && /home/doppler/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cmake/data/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" "/home/doppler/C++ Projects/test 2" "/home/doppler/C++ Projects/test 2/external/raylib/src" "/home/doppler/C++ Projects/test 2/build" "/home/doppler/C++ Projects/test 2/build/external/raylib/raylib" "/home/doppler/C++ Projects/test 2/build/external/raylib/raylib/CMakeFiles/raylib.dir/DependInfo.cmake" "--color="
gmake[2]: Leaving directory '/home/doppler/C++ Projects/test 2/build'
/usr/bin/gmake  -f external/raylib/raylib/CMakeFiles/raylib.dir/build.make external/raylib/raylib/CMakeFiles/raylib.dir/build
gmake[2]: Entering directory '/home/doppler/C++ Projects/test 2/build'
gmake[2]: Nothing to be done for 'external/raylib/raylib/CMakeFiles/raylib.dir/build'.
gmake[2]: Leaving directory '/home/doppler/C++ Projects/test 2/build'
[ 96%] Built target raylib
/usr/bin/gmake  -f CMakeFiles/test2.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/test2.dir/depend
gmake[2]: Entering directory '/home/doppler/C++ Projects/test 2/build'
cd "/home/doppler/C++ Projects/test 2/build" && /home/doppler/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cmake/data/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" "/home/doppler/C++ Projects/test 2" "/home/doppler/C++ Projects/test 2" "/home/doppler/C++ Projects/test 2/build" "/home/doppler/C++ Projects/test 2/build" "/home/doppler/C++ Projects/test 2/build/CMakeFiles/test2.dir/DependInfo.cmake" "--color="
gmake[2]: Leaving directory '/home/doppler/C++ Projects/test 2/build'
/usr/bin/gmake  -f CMakeFiles/test2.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/test2.dir/build
gmake[2]: Entering directory '/home/doppler/C++ Projects/test 2/build'
[ 98%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/test2.dir/source/main.cpp.o
/usr/bin/c++ -DGRAPHICS_API_OPENGL_33 -DPLATFORM_DESKTOP -I"/home/doppler/C++ Projects/test 2/external" -I"/home/doppler/C++ Projects/test 2/external/raylib/src" -I"/home/doppler/C++ Projects/test 2/external/raylib/src/external/glfw/include" -g -MD -MT CMakeFiles/test2.dir/source/main.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles/test2.dir/source/main.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/test2.dir/source/main.cpp.o -c "/home/doppler/C++ Projects/test 2/source/main.cpp"
[100%] Linking CXX executable test2
/home/doppler/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cmake/data/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/test2.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/c++ -g CMakeFiles/test2.dir/source/main.cpp.o -o test2  external/raylib/raylib/libraylib.a -lm -lpthread /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOpenGL.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLU.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.a -lm -ldl
gmake[2]: Leaving directory '/home/doppler/C++ Projects/test 2/build'
[100%] Built target test2
gmake[1]: Leaving directory '/home/doppler/C++ Projects/test 2/build'
/home/doppler/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cmake/data/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start "/home/doppler/C++ Projects/test 2/build/CMakeFiles" 0


Edit your question with the output of cmake --build . --verbose

Also, using glob to get a list of source files is an antipattern in Cmake.

Also, how exactly are you "running main"? Keep in mind that vscode has its own terrible "c++ runner" thing that completely ignores build systems like cmake and breaks down at anything that's not a self-contained file with no dependencies.

Did you check cmake template example: https://github.com/RobLoach/raylib-cpp/blob/master/projects/CMake/CMakeLists.txt#L36C1-L36C64 ? target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC raylib raylib_cpp)!

@Botje I added the output of cmake --build . --verbose, at your suggestion I removed glob and explicitly stated the main path. I run the code using VS Code, I just hit the run button.

Offtopic. I do not like this strange CMake practice: add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} .... Any cmake target should have well defined fixed name, so it should not depend on any variables.

Your CMake build seems to run just fine. Don't just hit "run" in VSCode, that is a completely different build system that does not understand dependencies or multi-file builds and, quite frankly, sucks. Instead, figure out how to run targets generated by the CMake extension or add a custom run configuration that runs your target.
